# plotrix: How to plotCI without the y-values. y-values are outside the confidence interval

Tags: r

How to plotCI without the y-values. I just want the interval to be plotted. This is because my y-values are outside the confidence intervals.

I tried: `plotCI(x, y=NULL, ui=U, li=L)` where all are numeric vectors; and it did not work

Now, if for one entry, `y=2`, `U=4`, and `L=3`, the interval will go all the way down to `2` (rather than down to `3=L`)

What I need is `y` (where `y` could be below or above the vertical confidence interval)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly does "did not work" mean?

Comment: Sigh...ok, I'll bite: why are your y values outside your "confidence intervals"?

Comment: I constructed a simple example:
x=c(1)
y=c(2)
U=c(4)
L=c(3)
plotCI(x, y, ui=U, li=L)
plotCI(x, y=NULL, ui=U, li=L)

Both, yield the same vertical line. Note that the lower bound should be 3 not 2. I may be doing something wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I wasn't asking about the code, I was asking how you could have a confidence interval that doesn't include your estimate.

Comment: I need to compare cutoff points from a theoretical model to a confidence interval that comes from data. In most cases, the cutoff point lies above or below the interval.

Comment: Ah, so in fact you are using plotCI for something well outside its intended purpose. I think you'll have better luck simply plotting the points and segments manually using `points` and `segments` directly.

Comment: Indeed, but to my surprise, plotCI does not let me plot just the interval (no y-values, no open dot inside). I just want the interval, and then add some y values

Comment: Your use case is not unreasonable, but since it wasn't foreseen by the original authors (me/Bill Venables/Greg Warnes), the function can't handle it.  In principle one could dig in to find out exactly why not, but it's probably not worth it -- easy enough to produce the desired graph as shown in the answer below.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If the answer below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716 for a full explanation

Answer (score 2):

Rather than dig into the details of what `plotCI` does and why it doesn't work with missing y values, I would do the old-fashioned version with `arrows()`:

```
x <- 1:10
L <- -(1:10)
U <- 1:10
ylim <- range(c(L,U))
plot(x,y=rep(NA,length(x)),type="n",ylim=ylim)
arrows(x,L,x,U,code=3,angle=90,length=0.1)
```

See also http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:graphics-base:errbars

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to add confidence interval using a dot chart:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tutorial-add-confidence-intervals-to-dotchart-2/

example code:

```
### Create data frame with mean and std dev
x <- data.frame(mean=tapply(mtcars$mpg, list(mtcars$cyl), mean), sd=tapply(mtcars$mpg, list(mtcars$cyl), sd) )

###  Add lower and upper levels of confidence intervals
x$LL <- x$mean-2*x$sd
x$UL <- x$mean+2*x$sd

### plot dotchart with confidence intervals

title <- "MPG by Num. of Cylinders with 95% Confidence Intervals"

dotchart(x$mean, col="blue", xlim=c(floor(min(x$LL)/10)*10, ceiling(max(x$UL)/10)*10), main=title )

for (i in 1:nrow(x)){
    lines(x=c(x$LL[i],x$UL[i]), y=c(i,i))
}
grid()
```